# Вопрос с анимацией через transform

Tags: jquery, javascript, css

Проблема: если 3 `li` стоят в ряд через `float`, и ширина первого плавно уменьшается до нуля, используя анимацию через `transform`, почему 2-й `li` не прилипает в процессе анимации?

```css
.anim_test ul li{
 float: left;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 margin-left: 2px;
 margin-right: 2px;
 background: gray; 
 list-style: none;
}
.anim_test ul li:first-child{
 -webkit-animation-name: 'movement';
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-name: 'movement';
    animation-duration: 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes 'movement'{
    
 from {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    }
    to {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="anim_test">
 <ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>  
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю там особенность в -webkit-transform: scale

Попробуйте как то так сделать:

```
@-webkit-keyframes 'movement'{

    from {
        width:100px;
    }
    to {
        width:0px;
    } 
}
```

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-
Если важно использовать именно transformation, то:

```
.anim_test ul li{
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    background: gray;   
    list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid red;

  -webkit-animation-name: 'people-go';
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: 'people-go';
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
.anim_test ul li:first-child{
    -webkit-animation-name: 'movement';
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-name: 'movement';
    animation-duration: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes 'movement'{

    from {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);

  }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);

    } 
}
@-webkit-keyframes 'people-go'{

    from {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);

  }
    to {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(-50px);

    } 
}
```

добавляем еще одну анимацию.

Comment: так будет работать. но у меня требование - сделать именно через transform

Comment: окей. см. мой апдейт.
Добавляем еще одну анимацию.

Comment: ваш вариант не работает, и нужно уменьшать width в рамках задачи

Comment: как не работает?... только что запустил -- работает. уменьшается ширина первого элемента, и к нему едут другие.

так можно или нет использовать width в рамках вашей задачи?... в любом случае, есть решение и с width и с scaleX.

Comment: сорри, всё работает, спасибо! а можно как-то без анимации people-go, только с movement? Очень громоздко. непонятно, почему в примере  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lLpeo li не прилипают. Должно прилипать по логике. Меняется width, элемент остаётся float.

Comment: Видимо не можно без дополнительной анимации. ...по крайней мере я не знаю.

Видимо такова особенность transformation. ...как бы коробка остается, но к ней применяются всякие эффекты, которые работают только с объектом на который применяется данный эффект, но не на что больше.

Answer (score 1):

Это особенность работы transform: scale(). Элемент изменяется в размерах только визуально, оставляя за собой место в потоке элементов таким, каким оно было изначально до трансформации. Аналогично как и изменение позиционирования элементов с `position:relative` - визуально он перемещается, а фактически остается на том же месте, оставляя там пустое пространство. Если необходимо сделать именно через transform и обойтись только одной анимацией то можно сделать следующим образом:

```css
.anim_test ul li{
  float: left;
  padding: 0 2px;  
  list-style: none;
}
.square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
}
.anim_test ul li:first-child{
  -webkit-animation-name: 'movement';
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-name: 'movement';
  animation-duration: 5s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes 'movement'{
  from {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
    margin-right: -50px;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class="anim_test">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <div class="square"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="square"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
         <div class="square"></div>
      </li>  
   </ul>
</div>
```